# Page is rendering as SSG rather than Static Nextjs

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am a bit confused as to why one of my pages is building as an SSG page rather than a Static page.

- /profile/page.tsx

  ```js
  import ProfilePage from "./ProfilePage";
  import getQueryClient from "@/app/getQueryClient";
  import { getTraits } from "@/utils/admin/collegeMethods";
  import { dehydrate, Hydrate } from "@tanstack/react-query";

  async function Page() {
    const queryClient = getQueryClient();
    await queryClient.prefetchQuery(["data", "traits", "order"], async () => {
      const traits = await getTraits();
      for (let key in traits.traits) {
        for (let subkey in traits.traits[key]) {
          if (subkey === "order") {
            continue;
          }
          delete traits.traits[key][subkey];
        }
      }
      return traits;
    });
    const dehydratedState = dehydrate(queryClient);
    queryClient.clear();

    return (
      <div className="flex-grow">
        <Hydrate state={dehydratedState}>
          <ProfilePage />
        </Hydrate>
      </div>
    );
  }

  export default Page;
  ```

  Here is the route after a build. Everything seems to be work fine, just confused as to why its not static. I am using nextjs 13.
  [image]

Comment: Can you try adding "use client" to top of the page 

https://react.dev/reference/react/use-client